# How to make javascript images responsive

Tags: javascript, css

I have a javascript banner rotation script that I can't for the life of me figure out how to add image styling to make them responsive. For example, max-width: 500px and width 100%.

It won't recognize those directives in the same way CSS does and just stretch across the whole page.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thank you!

```
  <center><script type="text/javascript"><!--

headers=
[
"<a href=\"http://example.com\"><img src=\"http://wvw.example.com/images/pictures/header-008.jpg\" width=\"\" height=\"\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\"></a>",
"<a href=\"http://example.com\"><img src=\"http://wvw.example.com/images/pictures/header-013.jpg\" width=\"\" height=\"\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\"></a>",
"<a href=\"http://example.com\"><img src=\"http://wvw.example.com/images/pictures/header-030.jpg\" width=\"\" height=\"\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\"></a>",
"<a href=\"http://example.com\"><img src=\"http://wvw.example.com/images/pictures/header-031.jpg\" width=\"\" height=\"\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\"></a>",

]
randomNumber = Math.random()
var show_headers = headers[Math.floor(randomNumber * headers.length)]
document.write(show_headers);
// --></script>
<noscript>
<a href=\"http://example.com\"><img src=\"http://wvw.example.com/images/pictures/header-013.jpg\" width=\"\" height=\"\" alt=\"Click Here\" border=\"0\"></a>
</noscript></center>
</br>
```

Comment: did you try width="100%" height="auto" and or almost same in css ?

Comment: o_O thats nice block of text...

Comment: I see every image has `width=""` and don't understand how you think that is the same as `width="100%"`

Comment: That's just the base code. I tried probably 20 versions of it. Height, width, auto, percentages, pixels -- it's never responsive. If I set width to 100%, it will stretch all the way across the page, even with a max-width directive.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the image's `max-width` property to 100% and `height` to auto, so that the image stays within the bounds of the parent. If it's going the full width, you'll want to set the parent container to a width of 550px (or whatever). You can do that via external CSS (probably preferable), or via [inline CSS](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/qt/tipcssinlinesty.htm) using the `style` attribute:

```
<img style="max-width:100%;height:auto">
```

Fiddle with external CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/r40fn9hg/

Comment: That makes perfect sense but how would I integrate that into the javascript as doing so breaks the javascript code. You can see how the existing width, height, alt attributes are not in quotes and have preceding/trailing slashes.

Comment: width=\"100%\" height=\"auto\" - the image still stretches all the way across the page and is about 20 x as big as it actually is in height/width.

Comment: Don't rely on the HTML attributes, set it in CSS. You just need to find the proper escape characters. `var str = "<a href=\"http://example.com\"><img src=\"http://wvw.example.com/images/pictures/header-087.jpg\"  alt=\"\" style=\"height:auto;max-width:100%;border:none;\"></a>";` An alternative is to just change the image URL with javascript, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/r40fn9hg/1/